# How to design Appium tests in Java using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, appium

I am writing Appium tests for the first time. I've created a common class for tests and I am not sure if I supposed to extend this class with JUnit.TestCase class or not.

If I got it right, if I decide to extend, I should start names of all the tests with "test" (testDoOne, testCancelSomething etc). If I decide not to extend I could just use a tag @Test and name my test methods any way I want.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use testNG framework instead of JUnit. For further read - http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-annotations-groups-depends/  . It's easy to grouping your @Test case in single suite(testng suite xml) and run.